# How to make vue + webpack run using direct access through URL locally?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I am working with an app and I’m planning of using Vue.js for the front end.

I’m just wondering on how I can work with Vue features like .vue files etc with webpack without running it like `npm run dev` I just want to make it work like if I want to open index.html then it will automatically load with the vue events/actions/ I’ve created for that file.

Is there any way where I can just access it through localhost/projectname easily since XAMPP has its own server? 
I’ll be running this app locally and will be using XAMPP so I don’t want the user to be like `npm run dev` and just want them to access through URL. 
Please enlighten me if this is possible or there is any workarounds.

Comment: Has my answer helped you? Or are you still with problems?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> All of these are solved by single-file components with a .vue
> extension, made possible with build tools such as Webpack or
> Browserify.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

To develop, you'll need to use webpack, which uses node, so `npm run dev` command is required.

However, after you're done with the development (or done for the time being), you can run the production command, which usually is `npm run build`, then it will compile it to the output `dist` folder.

You can then copy the files from that folder and use it wherever you want.